# Is it possible to take a screenshot of a website using python without having to actually open the website on my pc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I know that the selenium module can do this, however it has to actually open the site on my computer. The code that I have been using so far is:

```
site_name='any site here'
    try:
        driver.get(site_name)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bonfire\Webpage Screenshots\screengrab.png')
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bonfire\Webpage Screenshots\screengrab.png'))
    except:
        await ctx.send('Your URL is wrong or that site does not exist anymore.')
```

I was wondering if there was any other way to do it, without actually having to open the webpage. Thank you!

Comment: How can you take a screenshot without the content being on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/1.0.2/) module to take screenshots without opening the site on your computer!

```
import imgkit
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.jpg')
```

where you can also pass multiple URLs to take screenshots!

```
imgkit.from_url(['google.com', 'yandex.ru', 'engadget.com'], 'out.jpg')
```

There are more ways to make the website's screenshot. But, I prefer this, because we can take screenshots with just a line of code!

Comment: How does that work with multiple URLs if there only is one output file name? Does it make a sort of collage?

Comment: Hey! I downloaded wkhtmltoimage, and it works when I use it in cmd. However everytime I run it in pycharm it gives me this error: OSError: No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org